# Any tool to trace page fault and other related events for a specific file on iOS?

Tags: ios, instruments, darwin, dtrace, xnu

`System Usage(Instruments)` seems only trace explicit file io calls(`open`, `close`, `write`, `read`). `System Trace(Instruments)` trace `page fault`, but it is organized by call stack, make it hard to filter.

So any tool can trace the low level io events for a specific file?

Answer (score 1):

DTrace can do some of that (at least in Solaris, you’ll have to try it out yourself on macOS). The `vm` provider has probes named `fspgin`, `fspgout`, and `fsfree` which fire when FS-backed pages are paged in or out of memory or are freed if they’re unmodified, respectively. There’s also a more general one called `maj_fault` which fires whenever a page fault results in IO.

The only problem is that DTrace doesn’t give you a way to get back to the filename from those probes, which might be ok if you’re mainly page faulting on a single file, or might be really annoying if you’re trying to figure out which file is the one getting paged. However, you can still get the `execname` or `pid` of the process that’s causing the page fault though, in case that helps.

[Here’s](http://dtrace.org/guide/chp-vminfo.html) where you can see the documentation for the `vm` provider. There are some example scripts there, but this one is probably the nicest to use:

```
vminfo:::maj_fault,
vminfo:::zfod,
vminfo:::as_fault
/execname == "soffice.bin" && start == 0/
{
    /*
     * This is the first time that a vminfo probe has been hit; record
     * our initial timestamp.
     */
    start = timestamp;
}

vminfo:::maj_fault,
vminfo:::zfod,
vminfo:::as_fault
/execname == "soffice.bin"/
{
    /*
     * Aggregate on the probename, and lquantize() the number of seconds
     * since our initial timestamp.  (There are 1,000,000,000 nanoseconds
     * in a second.)  We assume that the script will be terminated before
     * 60 seconds elapses.
     */
    @[probename] =
        lquantize((timestamp - start) / 1000000000, 0, 60);
}
```

This prints out a timeline of memory activity for each type of fault, and the docs explain it in a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the System Usage tools rely on Kdebug to get their information. You can monitor Kdebug directly (if you're root) with the built-in ktrace(1) (or a third party tool like kdv (http://newosxbook.com/tools/kdv.html)), either of which will get you all the Kdebug messages, with filters you can apply later with grep(1) and the like. Using Dtrace won't work if you have SIP enabled (and is also painful in terms of performance) - so Kdebug makes for a good choice.